# REGEX to catch a specific tag

Tags: regex

I am trying to catch a series of tags with regex (for use in Atom on Mac):

```
<sup id="cite_ref-23" class="reference">[23]</sup>
```

So far I mustered this:

```
<sup.id="cite_ref-\[\d{1,2}\]".class="reference">\[\d{1,2}\]</sup>
```

I also tried something in the line of:

```
<sup.id\=\"\=.*(\d{1,2}\])</sup>
```

And this catches all of the stuff, but it doesn't *stop* on first iteration, but keeps on moving:

```
<sup.*>(\d{1,2}\])</sup>
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to catch value inside tag `[23]` or whole element?

Comment: No, I am trying to catch the actual tag, so I can delete it from the document.

Comment: Also, the [23] keeps on growing, there are loads of those with any two numbers inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is character sensitive, an extra or lacking one ruins whole process. Having that said, you have many like `\=\"\=`. Besides, you should use a non-greedy or restrictive match. Basically you are doing this:

```
<sup[^>]*>\[\d+\]</sup>
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/bO2kjG/1)

Comment: Thank you. I was working on this for the past two hours, and couldn't fix the bugger myself.

Comment: Who gave @revo a negative mark?!? The expression works as it is supposed to.

Comment: There is a known person who does this on purpose. I received this downvote 25 minutes ago and his online status didn't change in last 30 minutes!

Comment: This should be reported to moderators. Such behaviour is not in the spirit of community.